# Preferred clean style/patterns for generating Redis/Memcached keys?

Tags: sql, caching, redis, memcached

Was just wondering if there was a preferred way or even libraries to [somewhat] demonstrate/automate this.

In the past I've used hashed SQL queries as keys in particular instances, but it seems like it's perhaps possible to store by UNIQUE or PRIMARY keys alone in many instances for most use cases. (i.e. how they say on Redis' site, "**user:1000:followers**")

Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is really down to personal preference. Most people I know (and systems I've built or worked on) use the suggested `user:1000:followers` method.

This might be an informal standard, but it works and unless you have a specific use-case where it doesn't work (or can come up with something much better), there are probably more important things to worry about!